# How to pass a DataPath PipelineParameter from AzureDatafactory to AzureMachineLearningExecutePipeline Activity?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-machine-learning-service

- I am trying to read a file from a Blob Storage, load to pandas and write it to a BlobStorage
- I have an Azure Machine Learning Pipeline with a PythonScriptStep that takes 2 PipelineParameters and are DataPaths as below.

  ````py
  from azureml.core import Datastore
  from azureml.data.datapath import DataPath, DataPathComputeBinding, DataReference
  from azureml.pipeline.core import PipelineParameter

  datastore = Datastore(ws, "SampleStore")
  in_raw_path_default = 'somefolder/raw/alerts/2020/08/03/default_in.csv'
  in_cleaned_path_default= 'somefolder/cleaned/alerts/2020/08/03/default_out.csv'

  in_raw_datapath = DataPath(datastore=datastore, path_on_datastore=in_raw_path_default)
  in_raw_path_pipelineparam = PipelineParameter(name="inrawpath", default_value=in_raw_datapath)
  raw_datapath_input = (in_raw_path_pipelineparam, DataPathComputeBinding(mode='mount'))

  in_cleaned_datapath = DataPath(datastore=datastore, path_on_datastore=in_cleaned_path_default)
  in_cleaned_path_pipelineparam = PipelineParameter(name="incleanedpath", default_value=in_cleaned_datapath)
  cleaned_datapath_input = (in_cleaned_path_pipelineparam, DataPathComputeBinding(mode='mount'))

  from azureml.pipeline.steps import PythonScriptStep

  source_directory = script_folder + '/pipeline_Steps'
  dataprep_step = PythonScriptStep(
      script_name="SimpleTest.py", 
      arguments=["--input_data", raw_datapath_input, "--cleaned_data", cleaned_datapath_input],
      inputs=[raw_datapath_input, cleaned_datapath_input],    
      compute_target=default_compute, 
      source_directory=source_directory,
      runconfig=run_config,
      allow_reuse=True
  )

  from azureml.pipeline.core import Pipeline
  pipeline_test = Pipeline(workspace=ws, steps=[dataprep_step])

  test_raw_path = DataPath(datastore=datastore, path_on_datastore='samplefolder/raw/alerts/2017/05/31/test.csv')
  test_cleaned_path = DataPath(datastore=datastore, path_on_datastore='samplefolder/cleaned/alerts/2020/09/03')
  pipeline_run_msalerts = Experiment(ws, 'SampleExperiment').submit(pipeline_test, pipeline_parameters={"inrawpath"  : test_raw_path,
                                                                                                          "incleanedpath" : test_cleaned_path})```
  ````

This is the Script Used(SimpleTest.py):

```py
import os
import sys
import argparse
import pathlib
import azureml.core
import pandas as pd

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("datapreponly")
parser.add_argument("--input_data", type=str)
parser.add_argument("--cleaned_data", type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

print("Argument 1: %s" % args.input_data)
print("Argument 2: %s" % args.cleaned_data)

testDf = pd.read_csv(args.input_data, error_bad_lines=False)
print('Total Data Shape' + str(testDf.shape))

if not (args.cleaned_data is None):
    output_path = args.cleaned_data
    os.makedirs(output_path, exist_ok=True)
    outdatapath = output_path + '/alert.csv'    
    testDf.to_csv(outdatapath, index=False)
```

**Triggering this AzureMLPipeline from AzureDataFactory :**
The above code works fine by executing the ML pipeline in AzureMLWorkspace/PipelineSDK. I am trying to trigger the AzureMLpipeline from AzureDataFactory(AzureMachineLearningExecutePipeline) activity as follows

[image]

Tried a debug run as follows by passing 2 string input paths
rawdatapath = "samplefolder/raw/alerts/2017/05/31/test.csv"
cleaneddatapath = "samplefolder/raw/cleaned/2020/09/03/"

[image]

```
Current directory:  /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/workspaceblobstore/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade
Preparing to call script [ SimpleTest.py ] 
with arguments:
 ['--input_data', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/raw/alerts/2020/08/03/default_in.csv',
 '--cleaned_data', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/cleaned/alerts/2020/08/03/default_out.csv']
After variable expansion, calling script [ SimpleTest.py ] with arguments:
 ['--input_data', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/raw/alerts/2020/08/03/default_in.csv',
 '--cleaned_data', '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/cleaned/alerts/2020/08/03/default_out.csv']

Script type = None
Argument 1: /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/raw/alerts/2020/08/03/default_in.csv
Argument 2: /mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/cleaned/alerts/2020/08/03/default_out.csv
.......................
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/mnt/batch/tasks/shared/LS_root/jobs/myazuremlworkspace/azureml/d8ee11ea-5838-46e5-a8ce-da2fbff5aade/mounts/SampleStore/somefolder/raw/alerts/2020/08/03/default_in.csv'
```

It shows that the default path is taken instead of the pipeline parameter(*No such File or directory error is less important as the main point is the default path is taken instead of the pipeline parameters*). I doubt its because of pass the pipelineparameter as a string instead of a datapath.

**FINALLY THE QUESTION** :  How to pass a datapath to an AzureMLPipelineActivity from Azure Data Factory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[This notebook](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/intro-to-pipelines/aml-pipelines-showcasing-datapath-and-pipelineparameter.ipynb) demonstrates the use of `DataPath` and `PipelineParameters` in AML Pipeline. You will learn how strings and `DataPath` can be parameterized and submitted to AML Pipelines via `PipelineParameters`. You can parameterize input dataset and here is the [sample](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/parallel-run/file-dataset-image-inference-mnist.ipynb) notebook that shows how to do it.

Currently, `ParallelRunStep` accepts dataset as the data input.  you can add one more step before `ParallelRunStep` to create a dataset object pointing to the new data and pass to `ParallelRunStep`. Here’s [an example](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/machine-learning-pipelines/pipeline-style-transfer/pipeline-style-transfer-parallel-run.ipynb) of using multiple steps:

For output, if you use `append_row` output action, you can customize the output file name through `append_row_file_name` config. The output will be stored in the default blob. To move it to other store, we suggest to use another `DataTransferStep` after `ParallelRunStep`.
Please follow [this example](https://github.com/mlonazure/AzureMachineLearning/tree/master/AML%20Data%20Transfer) for data transfer step:

Comment: may be I am not understanding well, how can I dynamically pass path_on_datastore to a DataPath parameter when I am triggering a registered pipeline? please clarify, thanks.

Comment: If you follow the example above, the pipeline will have an input Pipeline parameter where you are able to insert the datastore name and path every time you trigger the pipeline.

Answer (score 2):

Got an answer from Microsoft(please refer to this thread [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/91785/azure-data-factory-how-to-pass-datapath-as-a-param.html)). Azure Data Factory  Product team confirms that there is no datatype supported for "DataPath" parameter today in Azure Data Factory(ADF). However, there is a feature already raised for the same and work is in progress for it. This feature will be a part of the November release.

Answer (score 1):

The input parameters seem to be defined as string, please try modifying them as Object datatype. As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/transform-data-machine-learning-service#type-properties), it expects object
{"Key" : "value"} parameters.

[image]

Comment: Hey @KranthiPakala-MSFT, thanks for the response. Could you please clarify where the datatype has to be object? 1. Should the arguments in the "SimpleTest.py" be str or object? 2. Should there be any change in the Azureml pipeline? 3. In ADF AzureMLPipeline activity, tried to pass the path as an object but still the AzureML pipeline picks the default instead of the passed parameter. Should I use a getmetada activity to create an object or just a string as object? Thanks for the clarification